# Can't run tests .idea/modules' does not exist

Tags: intellij-idea-2018

I have the spring-boot project with two modules
But Idea does not generate ./idea/modules folders those when I am trying to run tests I got next error

> ' Cannot start process, the working directory /home/../my_project_name/.idea/modules' does not exist

Reimport or rebuild the whole project not solve the issue.

Answer (score 12):

It seems to be a confirmed issue for Intellij IDEA 2018: [see this thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000162670-In-2018-1-1-version-Problem-with-Error-cannot-start-process-the-working-directory-idea-modules-does-not-exist-). The recommended solution worked fine for me when I was stuck with running unit tests:

> As a workaround please manually change the value from $MODULE_DIR$ to %MODULE_WORKING_DIR% for 'Working Directory' in Run/Debug configuration.
>   To change it for all new projects please update Default Run/Debug Configuration.

Hope that helps you as well.